# Why printf does not print anything in c with string?

Tags: c, debugging, data-structures

**> printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);**

This will not print anything in my output, but if I use `%C` instead it prints first character of a string.

Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lkg {
    char *name;
    char *gender;
    struct lkg *link;
} *new, *temp, *front = NULL, *rear = NULL, *new2, *front2 = NULL, *rear2 = NULL, *temp2;

int isempty1() {
    return (front == NULL);
}

void enqueue1(char *data, char *gend) {
    new = malloc(sizeof(struct lkg));
    new->name = data;
    new->gender = gend;
    if (isempty1) {
        front = rear = new;
        printf("\ninsertion sucess\n");
        printf("\n__________________\n");
    } else {
        rear->link = new;
        rear = new;
    }
}

int isempty2() {
    return (front2 == NULL);
}

void enqueue2(char *data, char *gend) {
    new2 = malloc(sizeof(struct lkg));
    new2->name = data;
    new2->gender = gend;
    if (isempty2) {
        front2 = rear2 = new2;
    } else {
        rear2->link = new2;
        rear2 = new2;
    }
}

void displayA() {
    temp = front;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}

void displayB() {
    temp2 = front2;
    while (temp2 != NULL) {
        printf("Name: %c", temp2->name);
        temp2->link = temp2;
    }
}

void main() {
    int choice;
    char *name, *gender;
        
    do {
        printf("press 1 to enter enroll in LKG A \n Press 2 to enter enroll in LKG B\n press -1 to exit:\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1) {
            printf("you are enrolling for lkgA\n");
            printf("enter the name and gender:\n");
            scanf("%s%s", &name, &gender);
            enqueue1(name, gender);
        } else
        if (choice == 2) {
            printf("you are enrolling for lkg- B");
            printf("enter the name and gender");
            scanf("%s%s", &name, &gender);
            enqueue2(name, gender);
        } else {
            printf("not a valid choice");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != -1);
    displayA();
    displayB();       
}
```

I have tried `\n` and `fflush` too but it doesn't work in my scenerio. I think I have made mistakes in pointers but don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: `char *name,*gender; scanf("%s%s",&name,&gender);` Both those pointers are unintialised. Writing to unintialised pointers is undefined behaviour. You have to actually set those to point to valid memory buffers. And you are supposed to pass the pointer to `scanf` and not a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: Can you guide me, where should i change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- you pass uninitialized pointers to `scanf()` for the `%s` conversion. You should instead pass pointers to actual `char` arrays.
- the `enqueue` functions must make copies of the argument strings as they will be overwritten by the next input.
- `main` has a return type of `int` and should return `0` for success.
- you should make most of these global variables local.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lkg {
    char *name;
    char *gender;
    struct lkg *link;
} *front = NULL, *rear = NULL, *front2 = NULL, *rear2 = NULL;

int isempty1() {
    return (front == NULL);
}

void enqueue1(char *data, char *gend) {
    struct lkg *new = malloc(sizeof(struct lkg));
    new->name = strdup(data);
    new->gender = strdup(gend);
    if (isempty1) {
        front = rear = new;
        printf("\ninsertion success\n");
        printf("\n__________________\n");
    } else {
        rear->link = new;
        rear = new;
    }
}

int isempty2() {
    return (front2 == NULL);
}

void enqueue2(char *data, char *gend) {
    struct lkg *new = malloc(sizeof(struct lkg));
    new->name = strdup(data);
    new->gender = strdup(gend);
    if (isempty2) {
        front2 = rear2 = new;
    } else {
        rear2->link = new;
        rear2 = new;
    }
}

void displayA() {
    struct lkg *temp = front;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Name: %s\n", temp->name);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}

void displayB() {
    struct lkg *temp = front2;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("Name: %c", temp->name);
        temp->link = temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    int choice;
    char name[100], gender[10];
        
    do {
        printf("Enter 1 to enter enroll in LKG A\n"
               "Enter 2 to enter enroll in LKG B\n"
               "Enter -1 to exit:\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)
            break;
        if (choice == 1) {
            printf("you are enrolling for lkgA\n");
            printf("enter the name and gender:\n");
            scanf("%99s%9s", &name, &gender);
            enqueue1(name, gender);
        } else
        if (choice == 2) {
            printf("you are enrolling for lkgB\n");
            printf("enter the name and gender:\n");
            scanf("%99s%9s", &name, &gender);
            enqueue2(name, gender);
        } else {
            printf("not a valid choice\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != -1);
    displayA();
    displayB();
    return 0;      
}
```